# nosetest - run all tests in subdirectories

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I am running the nosetest command below but it only runs the tests in the  first folder, i have extra tests in subdirectories. How do you edit the command to run all the following tests in all subdirectories of the folder i specified?

`nosetests -s -v --ckan --with-pylons=test-core.ini ckan/tests/legacy/*`

Here is the basic structure of the tests in the following directory

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/tree/ckan-2.7.3/ckan/tests/legacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write script that do generation of all required paths.

I use something as:

```
#coding: utf-8
import os
import logging
log = logging.getLogger()
skip_list = []

def get_test_files(cur_path, test_files = []):
    """ Find all files that started with test_ """
    cur_dir_content = os.listdir(cur_path)
    for i in cur_dir_content:
        full_path = os.path.join(cur_path, i)
        if os.path.islink(full_path):
            continue
        if os.path.isfile(full_path) and is_file_test(full_path):
            test_files.append(full_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(full_path):
            get_test_files(full_path, test_files)
    return test_files

def is_file_test(full_path):
    """ Check if file is test"""
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(full_path))
    if file_name[:5] == "test_" and file_ext == ".py":
        if is_in_skip(full_path):
            log.info("FILE: %s ... SKIP", full_path)
            return False
        return True
    return False

def is_in_skip(full_path):
    for i in skip_list:
        if full_path.find(i) >= 0:
            return True
    return False

def execute_all_with_nosetests(path_list):
    """ Test with nosetests.
    """
    #compute paths
    cur_dir = os.getcwd()
    paths = map(lambda x: os.path.abspath(x), path_list)
    relpath = "INSERT YOUR PATH"
    paths = map(lambda x: os.path.relpath(x, relpath), paths)
    paths = " ".join(paths)
    os.chdir("INSERT TEST RUN FOLDER")
    cmd = "nosetests -s -v --ckan --with-pylons=test-core.ini " + paths
    os.system(cmd)
    os.chdir(cur_dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_list = get_test_files("INSERT_BASE_PATH")
    execute_all_with_nosetests(test_list)
```

Replace strings with "INSERT" to your own folders. Also, correction of execute_all_with_nosetests function is needed.
I don't run it, but it is subscript of my test running script.

Comment: Wow that did the trick. Didnt know we needed to script it to cycle through it.

Answer (score 1):

You should execute all the test in the directory including the sub-directories if you execute the tests as:

`nosetests --reset-db --nologcapture --with-pylons=test-core.ini ckan.tests.legacy -s -v`

Hope this will help